# break statement issue - sonarqube

Tags: c#, foreach, sonarqube

i am analyzing my code using sonarqube and am running into a bug for the following method

```
public static AllocationRuleList AsAllocationRuleList(this SIGACORD.Policy acordPolicy)
    {
        foreach (var OlifeExt in acordPolicy.OLifEExtension)
        {
            var elements = new List<XmlElement>();

            foreach (var ele in OlifeExt.Any)
            {
                if (ele.Name == "AllocationRestrictions")
                {
                    var allocationRestrictionElement = acordPolicy.OLifEExtension[0]["AllocationRestrictions"];
                    return allocationRestrictionElement.AsAllocationRuleList();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

sonarqube is saying my `break` should be removed or made conditional. but, isn't it logically correct?

Comment: You're starting to iterate over a collection, and breaking out after the first loop. That's odd, and it's pointing out that it's odd.

Comment: It only allows you to run the first iteration, you could use `var OlifeExt = acordPolicy.OLifEExtension.First()` from System.Linq namespace, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid c# code, but sonar is not about that the compiler is. Sonar validates if you code does not have confusing constructions and this one is confusing. You do not want to iterate the collection you want the first item only. So your code should express your intention of it. So you should do

```
var OlifeExt = acordPolicy.OLifEExtension.FirstOrDefault();
if(OlifeExt  != null)
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` will cause the loop to exit after the first item. That defeats the purpose of the loop.

It's the same as this:

```
    // a for loop does nothing if there are no items in the collection
    if(acordPolicy.OLifEExtension).Any()
    {

        // no loop - we just take the first item.
        var OlifeExt = acordPolicy.First(); 
        var elements = new List<XmlElement>();

        foreach (var ele in OlifeExt.Any)
        {
            if (ele.Name == "AllocationRestrictions")
            {
                var allocationRestrictionElement = acordPolicy.OLifEExtension[0]["AllocationRestrictions"];
                return allocationRestrictionElement.AsAllocationRuleList();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
```

If you really just want to look at the first item in the collection then the code you wrote - a `for` loop with a `break` after the first iteration - will work. But it's confusing. Someone will have to read the whole thing to realize that the `for` loop exits after the first item. Then they will wonder if you meant to do that. Then they'll read some more trying to figure out what's going on.

If you just want to look at the first item in the collection then it's better to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to have `break;` in any loop if it is not based on some condition, like:

```
foreach (var OlifeExt in acordPolicy.OLifEExtension)
{
  if(OlifeExt == something)
  { 
    break;
  }

  // else continue looping and do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"break" means break out of the current loop (the outer foreach). If the value you are looking for isn't the first in the collection then you will always return null.

Assuming this isn't what you had in mind, something like this should work better:

```
public static AllocationRuleList AsAllocationRuleList(this SIGACORD.Policy acordPolicy)
    {
        foreach (var OlifeExt in acordPolicy.OLifEExtension)
        {
            var restrictions = OlifeExt.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "AllocationRestrictions");
            if (restrictions == null) continue;

            return restrictions.AsAllocationRuleList();
        }
        return null;
    }
```